# Any good books or other resources to learn how to do simulation experiments in R?

Tags: r, references, simulation

I am interested in learning how to conduct simulation experiments in R, and i have been trying to find a book or a course to do that. I have found either very long textbooks that have one or two chapters on simulation experiments or presentations on very specific topics that dont provide enough explanation and are not very helpful.

Do you have in mind any good resources that teach how to do simulations in R, how to calculate operating characteristics, maybe with some case-studies or worked examples?

Books that explain the use of particular R packages built for simulations are very welcome too!

Comment: Here's a great resource: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bR%5d%20simulation.

Answer (score 5):

A good place to start would be "Monte Carlo Analysis in Academic Research" by Paul Johnson in *The Oxford Handbook of Quantitative Methods in Psychology, Vol. 1*.

He has a .pdf of his lecture on Monte Carlo on his website: http://pj.freefaculty.org/guides/stat/MonteCarloExperiments/mcExperiment-1.pdf, which has some good advice (like creating segmented functions instead of one giant for loop within for loop within for loop...).

I would also familiarize yourself with all of the distributions you can simulate in R. Paul Johnson also has a *ton* of resources on each of these distributions. I would explore all of these folders: http://pj.freefaculty.org/guides/stat/Distributions/

I took his Statistical Computing course, and the book we used was [*Monte Carlo Simulation and Resampling Methods for Social Science* by Carsey and Harden.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1452288909)

One of the reasons you might be running into trouble with your searching is that people don't always call these resources "simulation" but "Monte Carlo." You might get better search results if you looked for "Monte Carlo simulation." Searching this on Amazon got me:

- [*Introduction to Scientific Programming and Simulation using R* by Jones, Mallardet, and Robinson](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1466569999)
- [*Introducing Monte Carlo Methods with R* by Robert and Casella](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1441915753)
- [*Monte-Carlo Simulation-Based Statistical Modeling* by Chen and Chen](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9811033064)

...among many others

Answer (score 0):

Chapters 8-11 here: http://www.moderndive.com/index.html

A whole Packt book about simulation: [Simulation for Data Science with R](https://www.packtpub.com/big-data-and-business-intelligence/simulation-data-science-r)